# A-Frame VR mode portrait uneven lenses

Tags: aframe, webvr

When I enable VR mode on my iphone from portrait is make the lenses uneven.
If I start from landscape more they are even.. 
See pics below

UNEVEN from portrait
[image: UNEVEN from portrait]
EVEN from Landscape mode
[image: EVEN from Landscape mode]